# How can I get PLA to stick to my printer bed?

Tags: pla, monoprice-mini-delta

I'm printing a model, sliced in Cura, on a Monoprice Mini Delta v2.

The model is long, about the width of the print bed. When I print it, the extruder drags the filament (which should stay in place) into the wrong position.

To summarize, my white PLA won't stick to the print bed (which is heated to 40 °C). Is the bed temp too low? Is the nozzle too high (200 °C)?

If someone could tell me how to get the PLA to stick- preferably a long-term option like print or bed temp - it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably the initial distance is too large, and you may increase temperature of the bed to 50 °C or use an adhesive. Could you provide some photos?

Comment: what's the print surface? ever since i moved to a slightly textured mat, i've not had to fuss with tape, gluesticks, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with 60 degrees on the bed and check the bed levelling. You shouldn't be having a problem with PLA if the levelling is fine unless your filament has gone bad.